# Does 差不多 (chàbùduō) imply "slightly less than" when comparing quantities?

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context, word, comparison

[差](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%B7%AE) implies a kind of deficiency, so I expect

> A比B差不多

to mean A is slightly "worse" than B in some way.  For example, I would expect

> 我比你差不多高

to imply I am slightly shorter than you.  I'm not sure if this is correct, as [差不多](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B7%AE%E4%B8%8D%E5%A4%9A) is also used to mean "about".

**Question**: Does 差不多 imply "slightly less than" when comparing quantities?

I could imagine a conversation along these lines (I made this up):

> A：你说那本书是50块，可是就是52块，你说错了。
>   B：哎哟，差不多吧。

where A is grumpy that the book was 52 yuan, when B previously told A that it was 50 yuan, but B says it's 差不多 (much the same).  In this context, it seems like 差不多 means "about" and not "almost".  Here 52 is greater than 50, so this raises some doubt.

Comment: 差不多=相差不多=the difference is small. Note that it doesn't mean worse

Comment: pretty much the same I think that the accurate translation. A比B差不多 I don't think that's the right grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

差 = 相差 (difference) ;差距 (gap)

不多 = not much

> 差不多 :
>
> (adj) not much difference/ not much gap between
>
> (adv): almost / about

Example of 差不多 as adjective:

味道差不多 (not much difference in taste) - *could be slightly better or slightly worse*

價格差不多 (not much difference in price) - *could be slightly higher or slightly lower*

Example of 差不多 as adverb:

差不多到了 means "we're almost there" (*not quite there yet, but close to*)

差不多死了  means "almost died" or "about to die" ( *not dead yet but will be soon*)

When A ask B how much is the book,  and B said: "**差不多**50块", it mean "it **is almost** 50 yuan" (= not quite 50 yuan)

When A found out the actual price is 52 yuan, he has every right to accuse B of lying.

And B's excuse: "52块, 50块 **差不多**吧?" (52 yuan and  50 yuan is **not much a difference** right?) is using 差不多 in a different way.

> *Does 差不多 (chàbùduō) imply “slightly less than” when comparing quantities?*

When 差不多 is used  as an adverb (is **almost**) + quantities, it dose imply “slightly less than”, But when 差不多 is used as an adjective (**not much difference**), then it only mean the objects are similar in some form of comparison.

> *A 比 B 差不多*

The correct form:

A 跟 B 差不多 = not much difference between A and B

A 比 B **差**不了多少 = Compare to B, A is not much **worse**

*A 比 B 差不多 is not grammatical*

Comment: It seems writing A比B差不多 was a bit of an embarrassing mistake.  Oh well... I guess I'll make many more mistakes along this path.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Also, 差（cha1）means difference, and 差（cha4）means worse.

Comment: @TooskyHierot Not always the  case. E.g.差(cha4)不多

Answer (score 1):

The most common phrasing is A*和*B差不多. 差不多，as a whole, means ***not much difference***.

You can say 你的身高和我差不多 or 我们俩个差不多一样高.

If you want to use 比， you can say 和我比你还差得远，你和我比还差得远 etc.

It's worth to note 你比我差不多 doesn't work quite well because 差不多 is almost a set phrase to mean *not much difference*(which is different from what you expect it to mean).